# Run multiple instances of Backbone or Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Is it possible to create and run more than one Backbone or Marionette application on the same page at the same time?

I've tried and I'm only able to get one of the apps to respond correctly to route changes.

I know you can feasible use iframes, but my project would benefit greatly from having the apps run on the same page, sharing the same styles.

Thinking about what could be causing the issue, and Backbone.history springs to mind, but I don't think that would really cause the issues I'm seeing now. In the backbone source, it says that backbone is designed to be able to run without access to a window object, but I'm not so sure.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this useful?

Comment: @tyler https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/1229

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a Backbone.history.stop & start somewhere in your code. If this is the case, change to Backbone.history.start unless Backbone.History.started

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's possible.  I made a jsFiddle with 2 versions of backbone loaded and routers made with each version of BB.  I used `backbone.noConflict` to use both versions.

http://jsfiddle.net/6YSLR/1/